# INNER JOIN with 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I'm having a problem inner joining multiple tables. When I join any of the three tables it returns the results correctly. For instance:

```
SELECT jobLink.*
     , trucks.*
     , employees.* 
  FROM jobLink 
  JOIN schedule 
    ON jobLink.jobID = schedule.id 
  JOIN employees 
    ON jobLink.empID = employees.id 
 WHERE jobLink.thedate = '2014-18-07' 
   AND schedule.id =  439
```

Will return the jobname and all the employees on the job under it.

As soon as I join the last join I get an empty result leading me to believe that my order is off or something. I'm open to other suggestions as there is possibly a better or more efficient way to accomplish this so I'm listing my tables below. Any help is appreciated.

jobLink table:

```
id     |    jobID    |   empID   |   copy   |   truck   |    thedate
_____________________________________________________________________
```

employees table:

```
id     |    name    |   abb   |   pos   |   current   
_____________________________________________________________________
```

trucks table:

```
id     |    num    |   sort  
_____________________________________________________________________
```

schedule table:

```
id     |    name    |   address   |   city   |   phone   |    email
_____________________________________________________________________
```

My query is currently:

```
 SELECT jobLink.*
      , trucks.*
      , employees.* 
   FROM  jobLink   
   JOIN  schedule 
     ON jobLink.jobID = schedule.id 
   JOIN employees 
     ON jobLink.empID = employees.id 
   JOIN trucks 
     ON jobLink.truck = trucks.id 
  WHERE jobLink.thedate = '2014-18-07' 
    AND schedule.id = 439
```

Each table has a different quantity of results. Schedule has 1 result but the rest will vary depending on how many employees and trucks are on the job (from the schedule). Im trying to produce something like this:

[image]

the employees wont end up under the trucks because i dont have that set up in the db tables but can be listed before or after the employee list. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `LEFT JOIN` on last join instead `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: @hRdCoder Presumably, the output is PHP

Comment: @ggulino If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: yes, the output is php sorry for not being more specific... @Strawberry after speaking to a colleague of mine, his suggestion is to change the structure. By changing the structure and adding a `job_truck` table and a `job_employees` table I am able to accomplish what I need by using inner joins. @RubahMalam yes i did try left joins but i am unable to accomplish it in one query. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you put that as the answer then and 'accept' it!

Answer (score 0):

yes, the output is php sorry for not being more specific... @Strawberry after speaking to a colleague of mine, his suggestion is to change the structure. By changing the structure and adding a `job_truck` table and a `job_employees` table I am able to accomplish what I need by using inner joins. @RubahMalam yes i did try left joins but i am unable to accomplish it in one query. Thank you for the suggestions.